# Can't list directory in bash

Tags: bash, linux-mint

update.sh

```
for item in *
do
    if [ -d "$item" ]; then
        echo processing $item
        cd $item
        git pull
        echo finish $item
        printf "\n------------------------------------\n\n"
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

The function will list current directories and enter each directory to execute git pull, it's work in Windows when use git bash, but show error message `update.sh: 2: update.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")` in my Linux Mint 13 Maya, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file `update.sh` has `CR+LF` [line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Change the line endings to `LF` and the script should work well.  You can use the utility `dos2unix` to convert the line endings.